# PHP Abarque div y span

Tags: php, html, div, class

buen día comunidad, tengo un problema:

Quiero que un div y span estén adentro de PHP, ya que realizan una función y lo necesito, o con algún otro metodo para que funcione.

```html
     <div class="alert"> 
  <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span> 
  <?php
  $quediaes=date("D");
$quehoraes=date("G");
$minutos = date("i");
$fecha = getdate();
$hora = $fecha["hours"];

if ($quediaes=="Sat" && 15 <= $hora && $hora <= 17 ) {
   echo '<h3>Ahora EN VIVO:</h3><a href="https://dominio.com">Alemania - Suecia</a>';
}
```

Esto necesitaría:

```html
 <?php
     <div class="alert"> 
  <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span> 
 
  $quediaes=date("D");
$quehoraes=date("G");
$minutos = date("i");
$fecha = getdate();
$hora = $fecha["hours"];

if ($quediaes=="Sat" && 15 <= $hora && $hora <= 17 ) {
   echo '<h3>Ahora EN VIVO:</h3><a href="https://dominio.com">Alemania - Suecia</a>';
}
```

PD: Entonces, quiero que ese "alert" se muestre con el style se muestre cada cierta hora, que ya está condigurado como se puede ver.

Comment: de favor explica mejor tu duda

Comment: Listo, ya explique un poco mejor, avisame si se entiende

Comment: ¿Te has fijado que esa comprobación se ejecuta únicamente una vez durante la carga de la página? ¿Deseas que una vez que el usuario cargue la página (aunque inicialmente no sea la hora) le aparezca automáticamente el popup en cuanto se cumpla la condición y llegue la hora deseada?

Answer (score 0):

Si se trata de que sólo aparezca el `div` cuándo cumple la condición:

```
 <?php
      $quediaes=date("D");
    $quehoraes=date("G");
    $minutos = date("i");
    $fecha = getdate();
    $hora = $fecha["hours"];

  if ($quediaes=="Sat" && 15 <= $hora && $hora <= 17 ) {?>

    <div class="alert"> 
      <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span> 
      <h3>Ahora EN VIVO:</h3><a href="https://dominio.com">Alemania - Suecia</a>
</div>
  <?php  } ?>
```